# How do I use a previous version of Keras (0.3.1) on Colaboratory?

Tags: keras, google-colaboratory

I tried pip installing 0.3.1, but when I print the version it outputs 2.1.4.

!pip install keras==0.3.1

import keras

print keras._version__

I am trying to train deepmask (https://github.com/abbypa/NNProject_DeepMask/) for which I specifically need 0.3.1.

Comment: use virtual environments....

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you've already loaded `keras`, then the second import statement has no effect.

So first `!pip install keras==0.3.1`, then restart your kernel (ctrl-m . or Runtime -> Restart runtime) and then things should work as expected.